# does r-squared say anything about statistical error?

Tags: r-squared

Can i estimate error bars based on the value of R-squared, when the signal is measured once (no SD)?

Normally I do not use statistics but the time has come and i have to calculate error bars.. The instrument measures signal y (once) in the function of x, for each point we get R-squared value. Is it possible to estimate error bars for the measured signal y in this case? I thought I could somehow use 1- R-squared but it only gives me information about the fraction that cannot be described with exact model, isn't it? Shall I in this case simply change the sequence in the way that each point (y) is the average of 3 measurements so as to get error bars or can I use R-squared for this purpose? I would be very grateful for any idea.

Raw data for x (magnetic field [Oe]), y (measured magnetic moment[Am^2]) and R-squared below: 
[image]

[image]

Comment: how many X-Y pairs do you have? Can you post a plot here or a short list of data? What is the question about relationship between X and Y are you answering?

Comment: Hi, I have ~ 70 pair. With increasing x (magnetic field) I am expected to observe the increase of magnetization (here magnetic moment). a short piece of raw data:  x (magnetic field in Oe), y (magnetic moment Am^2), and R-squared respectively: 11.21  0.0022  0.9948;
499.78  0.0314  0.9958;
1002.92  0.0573  0.9962;

Comment: Please add that extra info to the main post, not everybody reads comments!  If you have the raw data (seems like ...) obviously no problem, otherwise bad luck